# An exercise on Rotman's Algebraic Topology

Tags: general-topology

[image]

What is the open set in $Y/[]$?

I do not know how to prove it. Could anyone help me on this exercise?

Comment: I suppose $U$ is an open set in $Y/[]$, and want to prove   $\overline{f} ^{-1} (U)$ is open in $X/\sim$. I used $\ \overline{f} ^{-1} =  \upsilon _{1} \circ  f^{-1}  \circ    \upsilon _{2} ^{-1}  $, where $\upsilon _{1}:X \mapsto X/ \sim$, and   $\upsilon _{2}:Y \mapsto  Y/[]$. But I don't know how to do next.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $X$ is a topological space and $\sim$ is an equivalence relation on $X$ then you can form the set $X/\sim$. This set can be endowed with a topology (the quotient topology) by defining a set $U \subseteq X/\sim$ to be open if $q^{-1}(U) \subseteq X$ is open where $Q: X \rightarrow X/\sim$ is the natural projection sending $x \in X$ to its equivalence class $[x]$.

Now, suppose we have a continuous map $f: X \rightarrow Y$ preserving the equivalence relation. Let $\bar{f}: X/\sim_1 \rightarrow Y/\sim_2$ be the map induced by $f$. We want to show that $\bar{f}$ is continuous so pick an open set $U$ in $X/ \sim_2$. We need to show that $\bar{f}^{-1}(U)$ is open in $X/\sim_1$. Since $X/ \sim_1$ has the quotient topology it is sufficient to show that $v_1^{-1} \bar{f}^{-1} (U)$ is open in $X$ where $v_1: X \rightarrow X/ \sim_1$ is the projection map. You should be able to derive this fact easily.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot just write $\bar f^{-1}=v_1\circ f^{-1}∘v_2^{-1}$ because the inverse $f^{-1}$ is not a well-defined map from $X$ to $Y$. On the other hand, if you consider the functions above as set maps between the power sets, i.e.
$$f^{-1}:\mathcal P(Y)\to\mathcal P(X)\\ B\mapsto f^{-1}[B]$$
Then the above formula is true, though you still need to prove that it is valid, which makes essential use of the surjectivity of $v_1$.
Now, for an open set $U$ in $Y/□$, you have $\bar f^{-1}[U]=v_1\left[f^{-1}\left[v_2^{-1}[U]\right]\right]$. Do you know any property of $v_1$ which implies that this is open.

It's maybe easier to write $v_1^{-1}\left[\bar f^{-1}[U]\right]=f^{-1}\left[v_2^{-1}[U]\right]$ and compare with the definition of the open sets in $X/\sim$

Answer (score 1):

Thinking too much *ad hoc* is a bad habit.

**Hint.** Prove (if not already done) that for an equivalence relation $\mathscr R$ on a topological space $X$, the quotient space $X/\mathscr R$ satisfies the following property : for any topological space $Z$ and any map $f\colon X/\mathscr R \to Z$, $f$ is continuous if and only if $f \circ \pi$ is continuous (where $\pi \colon X \to X/\mathscr R$ is the canonical projection).

Then apply to your problem.